# Using OpenGL 4.3 in a C project

Tags: c, opengl

I need to use the function glDeleteProgram() but the compiler tells me that the function does not exist. I think my version of gl.h is too old but I can't find how to install OpenGL 4.3 in my project...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
```

I tried to include glext.h but it didn't work.

Comment: Updating your version of `gl.h` is not going to change anything. `glDeleteProgram (...)` is an OpenGL 2.0 function and your platform's unextended implementation of OpenGL does not support OpenGL 2.0. Extension occurs at run-time, so including a header will only give you the function prototypes and not a valid function pointer to call. The easiest solution is going to be to use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to handle run-time extension loading.

Comment: I really don't understand OpenGL versioning, I have OpenGL 4.3 installed in my computer so why is my GL/gl.h still in version 1.1?
What does GLEW do to fix it? You say that GLEW "loads extensions" but where are these extensions? Does it download these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a little bit of confusion exactly what purpose the `gl.h` header that ships with your platform serves. I will try to explain it better below, but be aware that this header and the platform's OpenGL library are very much related (and basically immutable). When you speak of "installing" OpenGL 4.3, you are actually supplementing (at run-time, rather than compile-time) the flimsy library that this header belongs to.

---

Platforms such as Microsoft Windows ship with a very primitive software implementation of OpenGL (1.1 in this case) but are designed in such a way that installed display drivers can extend/replace the software implementation at run-time. Microsoft refers to this system as **I**nstallable **C**lient **D**rivers.

For all intents and purposes, GLEW interfaces with your display driver and loads all of the parts of OpenGL newer than 1.1. Without using GLEW you are limited to the capabilities of the software implementation, which on Microsoft Windows was written in ~1997 and has never been updated since. `<GL/gl.h>` is always going to be 1.1 on Windows, because drivers are responsible for extending GL and you never compile/link your software directly to a display driver<sup>†</sup>.

GLEW is nothing special, you could read the extension specifications [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#arbextspecs) and write your own header with all of the extended function prototypes, enums and constant values you need... however, over the years this task has become ridiculously tedious (there are currently over 120 ARB extensions). GLEW basically packages all of the major published extension specifications into one massive library, and will load every one of the extensions your driver claims to support. This is effectively how GL versioning works, by the way, each new version boils down to a collection of ***required*** extensions.

---

<sup>**†**</sup> Back in the day, there were these bloody awful things called [MiniGL drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiniGL), and games like Quake 1 actually *did* link directly to extremely primitive and proprietary drivers from vendors like 3Dfx and PowerVR. Fortunately, we are way past those days.

Comment: Thanks to you for your excellent answer, I finally understood the reason of OpenGL compatibility limits.